# Print preview missing fields

Tags: c#, printing, uwp

I am currently working on some legacy code at my new job and I need a bit of help. The uwp application utilizes the print helper and print manager class. My problem is that my uwp the table is filled out and looks great when the application is running. However, when I hit the print button in the application. Certain fields will be missing in the print preview even thought they appearing on the app.

What causes this to happen. I tried inserting break points and tried watching how it gets data for the print preview but I am still stumped.

It runs this line of code before the preview is shown

```
            try
            {
                await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
            }
```

Comment: Do you mean when you entered into the print preview, some of the fields in the table you created in xaml didn't display in the print preview? When I created a table and entered the preview, it displayed well. So can you show a simple sample which can be reproduced this issue?